# Escape specific special characters in javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp, escaping, special-characters

Is it not possible to escape specific special characters like `#`, `%`, `&`, `+` `<`, `>`, `'`, `"`, `?` in javascript? I tried to find out, but didn't find a way to escape these above special characters.

The situation is like this - I have a list of fields which is accepting inputs (including all special characters) and adding in a normal JavaScript array. Then I am doing `JSON.stringify()` on the obtained array and passing to another JSP, which is accessing the array using classes of `com.google.gson` package. The issue is, while passing the stringified array, I am using `?`, `&`, etc special characters as delimiters that separates the parameters. That's the reason I need to escape the above special characters

My code is working for all the special characters except for the above ones.

I also tried the below code. But didn't work-

```
function escapeRegExp(str) {
    return str.replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\#\%\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "\\$&");
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by escape? In what context? Can you give an example?

Comment: Try `"\\$0` or `\\\\$0` for the replacement string

Comment: How about [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

Comment: @kufudo  by escape, i mean, i want to be able to pass those special characters for further usage.

Comment: @user1649068 for further usage by whom? Regex needs different escaping than HTML or Javascript literals.

Comment: @JanDvorak for further usage by java code. Basically I'm passing this string from javascript code to java code.

Comment: By which means, Java does not need any escaping by itself. You need different escaping to transfer a string through JSON (to anyone) than to transfer through XML. Nothing prevents you from developing a protocol that doesn't need any escaping at all.

Comment: If you are sending data with raw POST/GET, see mplungjan's comment, if you are sending data with JSON, see `JSON.stringify`...

Comment: It would make your question clearer if you showed an example input string with the corresponding desired output.

Comment: ok...will update the question in a while.